# How do I play Z.O.D.?

Tags: miniatures

As someone with a 3d-printer and a love of board games I was really excited when I found [Z.O.D.](http://www.illgottengames.net/zod-zaxis-optimized-dominion/) by [Ill Gotten Games](http://www.illgottengames.net).

The pieces looks great, and I have always wanted to try miniature figure gaming. *But how do I play it?* I have looked everywhere and I cannot find any rules or anything else on how to play it.

I did have the suspicion that as suchiuomizu answers the pieces are meant to be used with some other established rules/game, so let me modify the question a little bit: *How do I play with the pieces?* What kind of ruleset or other game can I use them for? Where to start?

Comment: This question is now a bit broad as there can be many different possible rules you can use for these miniatures.

Comment: Sorry about that. Feel free to edit. I guess my main inquiry is that I love the pieces, have a 3d-printer and want to use that as a starting point to play miniature games, but I have no idea where to start.

Comment: maybe change to where can i find rules for these ...

Answer (score 4):

You don't.  The site you linked to explained they are meant to be used for other games.  There aren't any rules specifically for these pieces.

> We designed these 3d-printable files to be optimized for home printing and cover a wide (and expanding) variety of themes and genres. Whether you use them for RPG dungeon-delves, wargaming scenics, or anything else, these tiles print and assemble fast and easy and come off your build plate ready to paint!

Answer (score 3):

ZOD says it's “digital files of modular 3D-printable terrain for tabletop miniature gaming”. These are **the tiles**, not the miniatures on the tiles, just in case that's not clear.

That said, they're cool tiles.

When ZOD is talking about tabletop miniature gaming, it doesn't seem to be talking about board games. It's talking about tabletop role-playing games, like Dungeons & Dragons which you might have heard of. There's thousands of those ([RPGGeek catalogues over 8,000](https://rpggeek.com/browse/rpg)). Many of those do not use minis or tiles, some will. Dungeons & Dragons is one of the ones that does. RPG Stack Exchange has [an intro to roleplaying](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/4457/what-is-role-playing-and-where-do-i-start) and [an intro to D&D](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/11033/im-at-a-loss-with-dungeons-and-dragons-how-does-one-play-it-anyway) available.

[The Ill Gotten Games Patreon](https://www.patreon.com/illgottengames) includes minis and even some creature designs for use in D&D, and lots of their posts have "dungeons & dragons" for a tag, so I'm reasonably confident that's the market they're targeting. It's also a market that predominantly wants stuff like this.

Tabletop Wargaming was also something they could've been referring to, but wargame players are not usually looking for tilesets the way D&D players are.